# Comparing StringBuffer content with equals

Tags: java

```
StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer("Java");
StringBuffer sb2 = new StringBuffer("Java");
System.out.println(sb1 == sb2);
System.out.println(sb1.equals(sb2));
```

Here both are returning false. How is it possible?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `equals` method of `StringBuffer` is not overridden from `Object`, so it is just reference equality, i.e., the same as using `==`. I suspect the reason for this is that `StringBuffer` is modifiable, and overriding `equals` is mostly useful for value-like classes that you might want to use as keys (though lists also have an overridden `equals` and `StringBuffer` is kind of a list, so this is a bit inconsistent).

Comment: As I just fell into the same pit, I'd like to remark that this is simply a **stupid design decision**:
Instead of `sb1.equals(sb2)`I'll have to write `sb1.toString().equals(sb2.toString())` (because this is what actually matters).
Maybe it's also the reason: Besides the current contents, there are internal attributes (like buffer capacity) which may or may not affect the view of equality.
Finally: `hashCode()` has the same problem.

Answer (score 31):

You are comparing the references to the StringBuffer objects rather than the actual strings within the StringBuffer.

`System.out.println(sb1.toString().equals(sb2.toString()))` would return true and I assume this is what you had expected or wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 12):

```
 1.  System.out.println(sb1 == sb2);
```

StringBuffer's equals method returns true only when a StringBuffer object is compared with itself. It returns false when compared with any other StringBuffer, even if the two contain the same characters.

This is because "==" checks the reference equality and since both sb1 and sb2 are different object references, so the output in this case is "false"

Still if you want to check if the content is equal in these two StringBuffer Objects, you can use this:

```
sb1.toString().equals(sb2.toString())

2. System.out.println(sb1.equals(sb2));
```

This is giving output as "false" because .equals() method has not been overridden in the StringBuffer Class. So it is using the .equals() method from its parent "Object" class. In the object class .equals() has been written to check the reference equality.

Note that sb3.equals(sb4) will return "true"  in case of String. Because .equals() method has been overridden in String class to check and match the content of two different Strings.

Answer (score 9):

The simple answer is that `StringBuffer` (and `StringBuilder`) do not override the base semantics of `Object.equals()`.  So `equals` on a `StringBuffer` will simply compare object references.

In fact, `String`, `StringBuffer`, `StringBuilder` and `CharBuffer` all implement the [CharSequence](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) interface, and the javadoc for this interface says this:

> This interface does not refine the general contracts of the `equals` and `hashCode` methods. The result of comparing two objects that implement `CharSequence` is therefore, in general, undefined. Each object may be implemented by a different class, and there is no guarantee that each class will be capable of testing its instances for equality with those of the other. It is therefore inappropriate to use arbitrary `CharSequence` instances as elements in a set or as keys in a map.

Also note that javadocs for `StringBuffer` (and `StringBuilder`) explicitly states this:

> API Note:
>
> *`StringBuffer` implements `Comparable` but does not override `equals`.* Thus, the natural ordering of `StringBuffer` is inconsistent with `equals`. Care should be exercised if `StringBuffer` objects are used as keys in a `SortedMap` or elements in a `SortedSet`.

---

But why?

At the heart of it is the fact that `String` is immutable and `StringBuffer` / `StringBuilder` are mutable.

- If two `String` objects have the same characters, they will always have the same characters.  So it is natural to treat them as equal ... and that is what `String::equals(Object)` does.
- If two `StringBuffer` objects can have the same characters now, and different characters a moment later ... due to a mutating operation performed by another thread.  An implementation of `equals(Object)` for `StringBuffer` that was sensitive to the (changing) content would be problematic.  For example:

  ```
  if (buf1.equals(buf2)) {
      // Do something to one of the StringBuffer objects.
  }
  ```

  has a potential race condition.   Another example is use of `StringBuffer` instances as keys in `HashTable` or `HashMap`.

At any rate, a deliberate design decision taken a *very long time ago* that `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder` would not override the `Object::equals` and `Object::hashCode` methods.

Answer (score 3):

`StringBuffer` seems to have no `equals` method of its own, so my first guess would be that `StringBuffer` inherits the `equals` method of `Object`, which compares using `sb1 == sb2`. Therefore, both methods yield the same result.

Answer (score 3):

both compares two references to objects (sb1 is one, and sb2 is second), thus both are different.

If You are trying to compare content - use method **compareTo(...)** in **String** class - that is - first get **String** content of **StringBuffer** using method **toString()** (**.toString().compareTo**).

Ps. as of JDK 5, there is another much faster class that behaves exactly as **StringBuffer** - it is **StringBuilder**<strike>, and is also</strike> but is not thread safe.

```
StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer("Java"); 
StringBuffer sb2 = new StringBuffer("Java"); 

System.out.println(sb1.toString().compareTo(sb2.toString()));
```

Comment: StringBuilder is not thread safe. From the SDK docs on StringBuilder: "compatible with StringBuffer, but with **no guarantee of synchronization** ", from the introduction paragraph here: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Comment: of course, my bad. read the doc of StringBuffer too quick, IT is suplemented by StringBuilder, thus it is meant for use by a single thread. sorry for that.

Comment: The fact is that it is faster because it removes the thread safety requirement from StringBuffer

Comment: Since JDK 1.6, lock elision makes the difference between `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder` negligible. However, I don't know the details, maybe lock elision is not able to catch more complex use cases, so it's always better to use StringBuilder, if you don't need thread safety.

Answer (score 1):

Wondering why `StringBuffer` does not override the `equals` method. Probably because the content of the object is obtained by the `toString()` method and which has the desired method.

Answer (score 1):

With [JDK/11](http://jdk.java.net/11/), one can now compare two `StringBuffer`s without an additional `toString`, this can be done using the newly introduced API -

```
public int compareTo​(StringBuffer another)
```

> Compares two `StringBuffer` instances lexicographically. This method
>   follows the same rules for lexicographical comparison as defined in
>   the `CharSequence.compare(this, another)` method. 
>   For finer-grained, locale-sensitive String comparison, refer to Collator.
>
> ***Implementation Note***: This method synchronizes on *this*, the current
>   object, but not StringBuffer *another* with which this StringBuffer is
>   compared.
>
> ***Returns***: the value 0 if this StringBuffer contains the same character
>   sequence as that of the argument StringBuffer; a negative integer if
>   this StringBuffer is lexicographically less than the StringBuffer
>   argument; or a positive integer if this StringBuffer is
>   lexicographically greater than the StringBuffer argument.

Sample usage :

```
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("null");
StringBuffer anotherStringBuffer = new StringBuffer("NULL");
System.out.println(stringBuffer.compareTo(anotherStringBuffer) == 0); // shall print 'false'
```

Comment: Posting this answer, since most of the questions pertaining to comparing the StringBuffer ends up here.

Answer (score 0):

Stringbuffer's `equals()` is not overridden. It does not compare values, it only compares reference value assignments. That is why you are getting false as they both are referring to different objects.

Answer (score 0):

That is tricky let me explain you in Object class equals method functionality is 
to match reference based on objects Sun developers had overridden the equals method
in Collection, String, Wrapper classes so except this classes if you apply equals method anywhere it will check reference not content because indirectly every class in java is the child of Object class so if you want to check content in StringBuffer class you can override the object class equals method
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

-> The String, StringBuffer and StringBuilder extends Object class. 
-> Object class contain equals() which compare two object memory address/ reference.
-> The equals() method is overridden in String class and it will check the

```
content.tostring()
System.out.println(sbuffer1.toString().equals(sbuffer2.toString()))
```

-> The equals() method of StringBuffer is not overridden from Object but implements Comparable, so it will compare reference equality, i.e., the same as using ==. in string class and equals() method in object.class. Thus, the natural ordering of StringBuffer is inconsistent with equals.