# Does the StringBuffer equals method compare content?

Tags: java, string, equals, stringbuffer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparing StringBuffer content with equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012305/comparing-stringbuffer-content-with-equals)

```
StringBuffer s1= new StringBuffer("Test");
StringBuffer s2 = new StringBuffer("Test");
if(s1.equals(s2)) {
  System.out.println("True");
} else {
  System.out.println("False");
}
```

Why does that code print "False"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012305/the-following-comparisons-are-returning-false-of-which-one-i-know

Comment: equals() method is of Object class. so every class has equals() method inherited from Object (Base class). String class has overriden equals() method to match exact content of to String. StringBuffer does not have overriden equals() method

Answer (score 7):

[StringBuffer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) does not override the [Object.equals](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method, so it is not performing a string comparison.  Instead it is performing a direct object comparison.  Your conditional may as well be if(s1==s2).  If you want to compare the strings you'll need to turn the buffers into strings first.

See http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html

Edit: I'm assuming we're in a java world.

p.s. If you're in a single-threaded environment, or your buffers are isolated to a single thread, you should really be using a [StringBuilder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of a [StringBuffer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html).

Answer (score 3):

StringBuffer equals isn't overridden to check content.  It's using the default "shallow equals" that compares references it inherits from java.lang.Object.

Comment: its overloaded or overrided?????

Comment: overridden or over... nope, i'm out :)