# How equals() method work in String Buffer?

Tags: java, string, netbeans, equals, stringbuffer

I tried the following code in netbeans and I received the output value as **`false`**
I want to know how the **`equal()`** works actually.

My code was:

```
StringBuffer x=new StringBuffer("Hey");
StringBuffer y=new StringBuffer("Hey");
System.out.println(x.equals(y));    // my output was false
```

Comment: StringBuffer does not override equals (i.e. it's comparing the references)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look at the source code`*`.

You will see that it just calls `Object`'s `equals`

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

Also consider using `StringBuilder` see [Difference between StringBuilder and StringBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/difference-between-stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer)

`*` If using Eclipse ctrl-click on the Object and if the source coded is loaded in your system, it will take you there

Answer (score 0):

`StringBuffer` does not override the `Object.equals` method, so it is not performing a string comparison. Instead it is performing a direct object comparison. Your conditional may as well be `if(s1==s2)`. If you want to compare the strings you'll need to turn the buffers into strings first.

> See http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html

**Edit**: I'm assuming we're in a Java world. If you're in a single-threaded environment, or your buffers are isolated to a single thread, you should really be using a `StringBuilder` instead of a `StringBuffer`.

[Does the StringBuffer equals method compare content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192032/does-the-stringbuffer-equals-method-compare-content?rq=1][1])

Comment: Instead of posting the link as an answer you should have marked the question as a duplicate. Link only answers are not good answers anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and I will do it from now..

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing to objects, not strings. And those are not equal. 
Call toString() on both Stringbuffers and compare the resulting strings.

Answer (score 0):

just it will compare weather two objects are equale to "this" or not
example
It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x) should return true

Comment: Add some reference code or example for batter readability of your answer.