# How to compare two StringBuffer Objects using .equals() method?

Tags: java, string, tostring, stringbuffer, object-to-string

The following code did not work. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the following code. Logically it should work...

```
package assignments;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class IsPalindrome {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                                      new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter a Word:");
    StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer(br.readLine());
    StringBuffer sb2 = new StringBuffer(sb1);
    sb1.reverse();

    if(sb2.equals(sb1))
        System.out.println("Palindrome");
    else
        System.out.println("Not a Palindrome");
}
}
```

Comment: You may want to use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer` (if you don't access it from multiple threads), as it's faster.

Comment: This might answer your query  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012305/comparing-stringbuffer-content-with-equals

Comment: `StringBuffer` doesn't override `equals()` inherited from `Object` so contents in the `StringBuffer` aint compared just their reference.

Comment: If you don't already know, you should read the API documentation rather than making assumptions about the behavior of methods. The [StringBuffer documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) says its equals method is inherited from Object.

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer if you can use StringBuilder.  This class has been deprecated for almost 10 years now.  http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Comment: Use equals() method of String class like below
sb2.toString().equals(sb2.toString())

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
sb1.toString().equals(sb2.toString());
```

because [StringBuffer#toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#toString%28%29) method returns the String value of the data stored inside the buffer:

> Returns a string representing the data in this sequence. A new String object is allocated and initialized to contain the character sequence currently represented by this object. This String is then returned. Subsequent changes to this sequence do not affect the contents of the String.

Comment: Thanks @darijan it worked but why can't we compare two stringbuffer objects directly?

Comment: Well, because `equals` method is not implemented in such way for `StringBuffer`s. It returns true only when a `StringBuffer` is comapred to itself.

Comment: @user1377586 `StringBuffer` doesn't have its own `equals` implementation so the call ends up in `Object`'s implementation that is reference based.

Answer (score 5):

In StringBuffer class `equals` method is not overriden as in `String` class. In `StringBuffer` it just looks whether the references are the same.
 Therefore you first need to convert that to a String and then use equals method.

So Try

```
sb1.toString().equals(sb2.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
System.out.println("Enter a line:");
String line = br.readLine().replace(" ", ""); // palindromes can have spaces
String reverse = new StringBuilder(sb1).reverse().toString();

if(line.equals(reverse))
    System.out.print("Not a ");
System.out.println("Palindrome");
```