# I have 2 Same value object of String Buffer Class. String equals() method Showing False result Why?

Tags: java, string

```
StringBuffer str1=new StringBuffer("hello1");
StringBuffer str2=new StringBuffer("hello1");
System.out.println(str1.equals(str2));
```

It will Showing False result Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing StringBuffer content with equals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012305/comparing-stringbuffer-content-with-equals)

Comment: See [`Object#equals`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Object.java#Object.equals%28java.lang.Object%29) code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no overriding of `equals` in the `StringBuffer` class. So it inherits the definition from `Object` class. And from Java API we know its behavior:

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating
>   possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null
>   reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x
>   and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

You have two different objects, so `equals` return `false` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

**StringBuffer** `equals()` method isn't overridden to check content. It's using the default "shallow equals" that compares references it inherits from `java.lang.Object.`

So

```
StringBuffer str1=new StringBuffer("hello1");
StringBuffer str2=new StringBuffer("hello1");
System.out.println(str1.equals(str2));
```

is Comparing reference that is why you are getting **false**