# its giving true for both values in boolean. how to improve the code?

Tags: java

import java.util.Scanner;

```
class Pal {
    public static boolean Palindrome(StringBuffer str) {
        StringBuffer str1 = str.reverse();
        System.out.println(str1);
        if (str == str1) {
            return true;
        } else { 
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Enter a string");

        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        str.append(input.nextLine());

        boolean result = Palindrome(str);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

How sholud I improve my code such that values come out to be perfectly correct?

Comment: try using .equals() method instead of == operator in your if condition to compare.

Comment: @kocko did you read the whole question ?

Comment: Different dupe. Although the answer would be the same :P

Comment: @BobTheBuilder did you read the whole question before marking this as a duplicate ?

Comment: @TheLostMind  Go ahead and mark with correct dupe ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (str == str1)
{
  return true;
}
else
{ 
  return false;
}
```

is the same as

```
return str == str1;
```

However, this still "won't work" correctly because

1. [Code should `equals()` for comparing objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java?lq=1) (including Strings and StringBuffers) and
2. [StringBuffer does not have a useful `equals`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012305/comparing-stringbuffer-content-with-equals).

A correction, taking both of these into account, would be:

```
return str.toString().equals(str2.toString());
```

In this case we first get the current String content of both StringBuffer objects and then compare it with `String.equals(String)`, which works as expected.

An alternative would be to bypass the StringBuffers in this case and directly use Strings; this would allow skipping the toString calls.

Comment: i tried this but this also didn't give me the correct answer.