# Why two equivalent property are not equal in Groovy

Tags: groovy, groovyshell, groovy-console

Please have a look at this simple code:

```
String.metaClass {
  getA = {delegate <<= delegate}
}

assert 'a'.a == 'a'.a
```

> ```
> Result: Assertion failed: 
>     assert 'a'.a == 'a'.a
>                | |      |
>                | false  aa
>                aa
> ```

Why the result is **FALSE**?

I am working at Groovy 2.4.7 on Windows 7 SP1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LeftShift on a String in Groovy generates a `StringBuffer` ([docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#leftShift(java.lang.Object)))

So `'a'.a == 'a'.a` is trying to do equals on two StringBuffers.

You can't do that with `StringBuffer` as the `equals` method isn't overloaded, and [just checks if they are the same instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012305/comparing-stringbuffer-content-with-equals)

Comment: Got !   So it would be   { (delegate <<= delegate) as String }    Thank you very much !

Comment: Or just `delegate + delegate`