# output should be string matched but it didn't

Tags: java, string

public class reverse_string {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    StringBuffer s1 =  new StringBuffer("madam");
    System.out.print(s1);
    StringBuffer s2 = new StringBuffer(s1.reverse());
    System.out.print("\n"+s2);


    if(s1.equals(s2))
    {
        System.out.print("\nreal string and reverse string are matched");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print("\nreal string and reverse string are not matched");
    }
```

}
}

Comment: Where does `javascript` and `arrays` and `swing` come in to play here?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012305/comparing-stringbuffer-content-with-equals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing two `StringBuffer` instantes, not the strings itself.

Try adding `.toString()` to convert them to a String.

Answer (score 0):

`StringBuffer` will do a reference comparison with equals. Since they are not the same object, the comparison returns false.

change your code to

```
s1.toString().equals(s2.toString())
```

this will compare the values of the Strings.

Also: JavaScript and Java are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

StringBuffer doesn't override equals() from String,  its equals() method is the one inherited from java.lang.Object, which returns true if and only if "==" would be true. That is, it compares the references of the two objects, which are not equal.