# Java program output should be true , But its return false why?

Tags: java, string, stringbuffer

I am checking if a String `"nitin"` is a palindrome but it's returning false.

Please anyone help me to shorout this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("nitin");
    sb.reverse();
    String rev = sb.toString();

    System.out.println(sb);
    System.out.println(rev);

    if (sb.equals(rev)) {
        System.out.println("true");
    } else {
        System.out.println("false");
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012305/comparing-stringbuffer-content-with-equals (it's a different question, but the answer also applies here)

Answer (score 4):

You are comparing the StringBuffer with the String.
Try with `if (sb.toString().equals(rev)) {`

Comment: In addition, there is also a mistake in regards to the `str.reverse()` part that I addressed.

Answer (score 1):

`sb` is a *StringBuffer*, `rev` is a *String*. These two objects of different types cannot be compared for "String value equality" with each other.

Use `if (sb.toString().equals(rev))`: this way you compare if two strings are equal, as `sb.toString()` is converted to a String.

Also, it is wrong at the beginning to reverse `sb`. That is because at the time you declare `String rev = sb.toString()`, `sb` is already reversed. Unreverse `sb` by calling `sb.reverse()` again after declaring `rev`. Your final code should be

```
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("nitdin");
    sb.reverse(); // reversed sb
    String rev = sb.toString(); // rev is reversed sb to String
    sb.reverse(); // unreversed sb

    ...

    if (sb.toString().equals(rev)) // String-string comparison
```

Comment: String rev=sb.toString(); check this line

Comment: "*They cannot be compared.*" - They can. And the fact that they can is the cause of OPs problem. It is just always `false`.

Comment: @Mulliganaceous Why is it "not useful"? When is a comparision "useful"? I would tend to choose a neutral wording.

Answer (score 0):

You might misunderstand the StringBuffer and String. Your code might need to change

```
    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer("nitin");
    String before = sb.toString();
    sb.reverse();
    String after = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(before);
    System.out.println(after);
    System.out.println(before == after);
    if(before.equals(after)){
        System.out.println("true");
    }else{
        System.out.println("false");
    }
```